# Drush for Drupal 4.7

Tags: drush

I'm trying to find a version of Drush that is compatible with Drupal 4.7. I know it's old and lame and long time ago deprecated but I really need it for a project I'm currently involved in.
I've tried to search it but without any luck.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in the last page of the [releases for drush](https://www.drupal.org/node/97249/release?&page=3) on drupal.org (right at the bottom, unsurprisingly).

As Greg mentions in the comments, Drush 1.x is a module so it needs to be put in the modules folder and enabled.

Comment: The first Drush version was build by Arto Bendiken for Drupal 4.7 and that is the version I'm looking for. Than it was rewritten for Drupal 5.

Comment: Cool, the hunt is on then...;)

Comment: And here it is! https://www.drupal.org/node/97249/release?&page=3

Comment: Cool! Now I just have to make it work :)

Comment: Note that Drush 1.x was a module, so put it in your modules folder and enable it.  Also, all of the old versions of Drush are still tagged on GitHub, even though the summary table only goes back to Drush 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the dev version [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/99950)..

### "REQUIREMENTS

This version of drush is designed for Drupal 4.7.x running on a Unix
platform."